# jQuery Validation plugin - Validating hidden input skips few validations

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a hidden input field type of file like:

```
<label for="addAttachment1" class="btn btn-default">Add Attachment</label>
<input id="addAttachment1" class="hide" name="addAttachment1" type="file" />
```

I use the **label** to show an image for uploading a file like:
[image]

I've client-side validations for file upload that I'm implemented using **jQuery validation** library:

```
$('#applicationForm').validate({
ignore: "not:hidden",
rules: {
addAttachment1: {
            extension: 'jpg,png,jpeg,pdf', 
            filesize: true,
            required: true
        }

},
messages: {   
addAttachment1: {
            extension: 'Only images or document of pdf type are allowed.',
            filesize: 'Files upto the maximum size of 25MB are allowed.',
            required: 'This field is required.'
        }
}

});
```

What's happening here now is that only validation for **required** is executing and not for other parameters. Can anyone suggest why this is happening. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A "hidden" input field is `type="hidden"`... you have `type="file"` input that you're hiding, presumably through CSS.  There is no such thing as a rule called `filesize`, and `ignore: "not:hidden"` is telling it to IGNORE validation on everything that is not hidden.

Comment: The `required` rule is always the first rule that is going to show on an empty field.  Please show the relevant CSS and construct a jsFiddle demo of this problem so we can better help you.  Otherwise, with what little you've shown, I am unable to reproduce what you describe.

Comment: @Sparky, I found the solution. And for the filesize, I created a method for checking the filesize of the file. Thanks for the reply!!

Comment: If you found the solution, please post it below as an answer for the benefit of others.